# Is there any specific meaning of 'export' in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, cinema

When I saw Shape of Water, the movie, I heard the following dialogue:

> Now, that's one thing.
>   That's real decent of him.
>   But the other kind of decency...
>   it doesn't really matter.
>   We sell it, but it's an *export*.
>   We sell it because
>   we don't use it.

I didn't get the meaning of *'export'*. Why was the general talking about *export* all of a sudden? Is there any hidden meaning of *'export'*?

Comment: I suggest you ask this on https://movies.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'd guess that 'export' is used here as a metaphor, 'anything "sold" (/ peddled) to make "money" (gain favour with / favours from) others'. You probably won't find this metaphorical sense in many dictionaries.